# 'main' has not been registered AppRegistry - react native expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I was running expo sdk 36 until this morning when I upgraded to sdk 38 using the expo upgrade command.
After installation and starting the terminal using expo r -c, I am getting the error in the image below.
I have restarted the terminal severally, but still does not work

[image]

Answer (score 0):

helped me to use `expo@38.0.8` and run `expo start --no-dev --minify -c`

Comment: Please add an explanation, indicating how or why this suggestiin solves  the OP's issue. This will increase long term value and quality of your contribution, help future visitors apply that knowledge to their own code, and increase likeliness of receiving upvotes. Code only answers are generally frowned upon in SO.